# Summary data for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

`Describe()` doesn't do exactly what I'd like - so I'm rolling my own version.

The following works fine apart from the final metric 'Num Unique Values' which is returning numbers but they are not correct - I guess I'm using apply incorrectly?

```
pd.DataFrame({
        'Max':d.max(), 
        'Min':d.min(), 
        'Count':d.count(axis = 0),
        'Count Null':d.isnull().sum(),
        'Count Zero':d[d==0].count(),
        'Num Unique Values':d.apply(lambda x: x.nunique())
    })
```

Comment: What about `'Num Unique Values':len(d.unique())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it works nice:

```
print(df.apply(lambda x: x.nunique()))
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,2,1],
                   'B':[4,5,6,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,1],
                   'D':[1,3,5,9]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  4  7  1
1  2  5  8  3
2  2  6  9  5
3  1  4  1  9

print (df.apply(lambda x: x.nunique()))
A    2
B    3
C    4
D    4
dtype: int64
```

Another solution:

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: len(x.unique())))
A    2
B    3
C    4
D    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: so I was correct in the first place?! Let me check the numbers

Comment: I should have more confidence in myself!!

Comment: The best is test it in small dataframe. i think.

Comment: I know  - "The Curse of Stackoverflow"  def. sometimes easier to add a question to SO than spend 2 minutes researching the answer